# OpenGL displaying white textures

Tags: c++, opengl

I have trouble displaying a texture using OpenGL and C++. I am loading the texture from a RGB Raw file, binding it to a  texture, but when I am trying to display the texture on a quad,  the texture is white. I am using glGetError and it catches no errors. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>       // Standard header for MS Windows applications
#include <GL/gl.h>         // Open Graphics Library (OpenGL) header
#include <GL/glut.h>       // The GL Utility Toolkit (GLUT) Header
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    char* title;
    float field_of_view_angle;
    float z_near;
    float z_far;
} glutWindow;
glutWindow win;
float rotation, distance1;
bool light=TRUE;
bool trans=FALSE;
GLuint tex;

void drawFlatFace(float size)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f (0, 0);
        glVertex3f(-size, -2*size, size);
        glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0);
        glVertex3f(size, -2*size, size);
        glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f(size, 2*size, size);
        glTexCoord2f (0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f(-size, 2*size, size);
    glEnd();
}

void drawBlock(float size){
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glPushMatrix();
        drawFlatFace (size);
        glRotatef (90, 0, 1, 0);
        drawFlatFace (size);
        glRotatef (90, 0, 1, 0);
        drawFlatFace (size);
        glRotatef (90, 0, 1, 0);
        drawFlatFace (size);
    glPopMatrix();
}

GLuint loadTexture(const char * filename) {
    GLuint text[1];
    GLubyte* bits = new GLubyte[512*256*3];
    FILE *file;
    fopen_s(&file,filename,"rb");
    fread(&bits,(512*256*3),1,file);
    fclose(file);
    glGenTextures(1,&text[0]); 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,text[0]);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3,256,512,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,bits);
    free(bits);
    return text[0];
}

void display() 
{
    GLenum err;
    err = glGetError();
    if (err != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "OpenGL error: " << gluErrorString(err) << endl;
    }

    tex=loadTexture("tex.raw");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);          // Clear Screen and Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt( 10+distance1 ,1.4,0, 0,0,0, 0,1,0);                    // Define a viewing transformation
    glRotatef(rotation, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    drawBlock(3);
    if (light)  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);      // Enable Lighting
    else glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);      // Disable Lighting
    if (trans) glEnable (GL_BLEND);  // Enable Transparency
    else glDisable(GL_BLEND);      // Disable Transparency
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void initialize () 
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                                                // select projection matrix
    glViewport(0, 0, win.width, win.height);                                    // set the viewport
    glLoadIdentity();                                                           // reset projection matrix
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat) win.width / win.height;
    gluPerspective(win.field_of_view_angle, aspect, win.z_near, win.z_far);     // set up a perspective projection matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                                                 // specify which matrix is the current matrix
    glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST );                        // specify implementation-specific hints
    GLfloat amb_light[] = { 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0 };
    GLfloat diffuse[] = { 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0 };
    GLfloat specular[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 };
    glLightModelfv( GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, amb_light );
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular );
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse );
    GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0, 0.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
    glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
    //glLightModeli( GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_FALSE );

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                        // Enable Texture Mapping
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                        // Enable Smooth Shading
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);                   // Black Background
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                         // Depth Buffer Setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                        // Enables Depth Testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                         // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}


void keyboard ( int key, int mousePositionX, int mousePositionY )       
{ 
    switch ( key ) 
  {

    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        if (distance1<9){
        distance1=distance1+.3;
        }
        break;      

    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        if (distance1>-9){
        distance1=distance1-.3;
        }
        break;      

    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        rotation=rotation-2;
        break;      

    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        rotation=rotation+2;
        break; 

    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
        light=TRUE;
        break; 

    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
        light=FALSE;
        break; 

    case GLUT_KEY_HOME:
        trans=TRUE;
        break; 

    case GLUT_KEY_END:
        trans=FALSE;
        break; 


    default:      
      break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // set window values
    win.width = 800;
    win.height = 600;
    win.title = "Test Texture";
    win.field_of_view_angle = 45;
    win.z_near = 1.0f;
    win.z_far = 500.0f;

    // initialize and run program
    glutInit(&argc, argv);                                      // GLUT initialization
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );  // Display Mode
    glutInitWindowSize(win.width,win.height);                   // set window size
    glutCreateWindow(win.title);                                // create Window
    // Callback functions
    glutDisplayFunc(display);                                   // register Display Function
    glutIdleFunc( display );                                    // register Idle Function
    glutSpecialFunc( keyboard );                                // register Keyboard Handler
    initialize();
    glutMainLoop();                                             // run GLUT mainloop
    return 0;
}
```

I want to add that the Raw file is displayed correctly when loaded in IrfanView as 256x512, 24BPP, RGB (the size is 393,216 bytes or 3*512*256)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Shouldn't be in your main intialisation, but instead needs to be done when setting up the texture itself (i.e. after binding).

You may also want to set the MAG_FILTER, and the texture coordinate wrapping modes, as a general rule.

Also, you appear to be loading the texture *every* time you render. Don't do that, performance will be terrible and you'll run out of memory as GL will keep allocating new textures.

Comment: I added 
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
in the loadTexture and I moved the call to it in init (so the texture is created only once). I still get a white texture when I compile in debug mode, but in release mode I get some nice White-Cyan-Magenta-Yellow stripes :(

Comment: Is your file actually being read correctly? You're not error checking any of the file reading.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I checked my code and you were right: the texture was not loading correctly from the file. I had: 
fread(&bits,(512*256*3),1,file);   
instead of: 
fread(bits,(512*256*3),1,file);   
That is what happens when you stay up until 7:00am :)